# How to display client's data on the terminal using node.js and web sockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, client, message

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8082 });

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  console.log("New client connected!");

  ws.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log("Client has sent us: ${data}");
  });

  //ws.send(data.toUpperCase());

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client has disconnected!");
  });
});
```

Here, the message displays on the dev tools network panel under the localhost. But, in the node terminal, it displays as Client has sent us: ${data} while the expected result to be Client has sent us: Whatever the message sent by the client.
I will attach the screenshot of the terminal herewith. Thanks in advance.[Image of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlEwQ.png)

Comment: To Print proper message either use ```console.log(`Client has sent us: ${data}`);``` or `console.log("Client has sent us: ", data);`

Comment: Thanks, Sandip. Didn't know about the backticks in modern JavaScript.